# Could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode, Connection is already Closed ERROR

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, sybase, connection-pooling

While trying to connect to an external `Sybase` DB, I am getting the below stacktrace. However when I restart the process of connecting to DB, It works perfectly fine thereafter.

I am using the below configurations. Seems like the connection is getting closed abruptly and once I restart the process it creates a new connection again. Do I have to configure any `parameter` in the `DataSource` or `connection pool` to keep the `connection` open and not close it abruptly?

**DataSource**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="******"/>
        <property name="username" value="*******"/>
        <property name="password" value="*******" />
        <property name="connectionProperties" value="ENCRYPT_PASSWORD=true;JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider" />             
        
    </bean>
```

**SessionFactory**

```
<bean id="hibernateTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate"
    scope="prototype">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>************</value> 
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**STACK TRACE**

```
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: Hibernate operation: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode; SQL [???]; JZ0C0: Connection is already closed.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: JZ0C0: Connection is already closed.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:106)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertJdbcAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:410)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:339)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JZ0C0: Connection is already closed.
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.checkConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:63)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.isAutoCommit(ConnectionManager.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.afterNontransactionalQuery(JDBCContext.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.afterOperation(SessionImpl.java:417)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1701)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
    at com.b2conshore.testing.B2COnshoreSybaseTesting$1.doInHibernate(B2COnshoreSybaseTesting.java:39)
    at com.b2conshore.testing.B2COnshoreSybaseTesting$1.doInHibernate(B2COnshoreSybaseTesting.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Is there a firewall between the application and the database.If yes this might be a probable cause of connection getting killed.Try putting these pool properties which will test the idle connection and test the connection before handing out to the application testOnBorrow=true,testWhileIdle=true along with the validationQuery property set. Include these properties in dataSource bean

Comment: You can find more about these properties here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jdbc-pool.html